# How do I organize block elements with translation in slim template engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Let's say we have a paragraph element block `<p>` which has different children elements such as `<strong>`.

From the same content in different language, the order may be different. For example:

> **English**: 
>   This is a paragraph with sample content and **bold content** here and *italic here*.

Corresponding Slim will be

```
p
  | This is a paragraph with sample content and
  b bold content
  | here and
  em italic here
```

Now we have chinese, due to the difference in language semantics, may result in difference in the bold text / italic text position:

> **Chinese**: **Bold的字** 和 *italic的字* 會在不同位置出現。

Resulting Slim becomes:

```
p
  b Bold的字
  | 和
  em italic的字
  | 會在不同位置出現。
```

I wonder what is the best way to organize translation content? Can I still store them in `.yml` file?